# Reverse order for GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to select **first** value for every hour from my db. But I don't know how to reverse order on GROUP BY statement.
How can i rewrite my query (now it selects **last** value in hour)?

```
SELECT HOUR(`time`) as hour, mytable.*
FROM mytable
WHERE DATE(`time`) ="2015-09-12" GROUP BY HOUR(`time`) ORDER BY `time` ASC;
```

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that you are selecting a record for each hour. Which record that is selected for the grouped value is not determined. Problem isn't 'reversing the order for group by', it is that group by in no way specifies which rows values are returned for fields that are not aggregate fields and which are not in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gave me expected result:

```
SELECT HOUR(`time`) as hour, sortedTable.* FROM
(SELECT  electrolysis.* FROM electrolysis
    WHERE DATE(`time`)='2015-09-12' ORDER BY `time`) as sortedTable
GROUP BY HOUR(`time`);
```

Comment: This is no more certain to work than the original query. Which rows values chosen from sortedTable for a particular hour are not defined, so could be from any row from that hour (or indeed no requirement that the different columns values even come from the same row).

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the MIN HOUR in sub query , try using the query:

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE `time` IN (
SELECT MIN(HOUR(`time`)) as `hour`
FROM mytable
WHERE DATE(`time`) ="2015-09-12" 
GROUP BY HOUR(`time`) ) ORDER BY `time` ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks, but no - i've received same data (last entry for every hour).

Comment: I have same result with MIN too.

Comment: Too heavy query, can't wait it ends. But thanks for idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
SELECT sub0.min_time, 
        mytable.*
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(`time`) AS min_time
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY HOUR(`time`)
) sub0
ON mytable.`time` = sub0.min_time
WHERE DATE(`time`) ="2015-09-12" 
ORDER BY `time` ASC
```

This is using a sub query to get the smallest time in each hour. This is then joined back against your main table on this min time to get the record that has this time.

Note that there is a potential problem here if there are multiple records that share the same time as the smallest one for an hour. There are ways around this, but that will depend on your data (eg, if you have a unique id field which is **always** ascending with time then you could select the min id for each hour and join based on that)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems i've found simpler solution

Comment: What is the solution? As simpler ways (such as the one suggested by @Arrovil ) might appear to work they are using behaviour that is not defined and so might not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query, which is more optimized just make sure that time field should be indexed.

```
SELECT HOUR(m.time), m.* 
FROM mytable AS m
JOIN
(
SELECT MIN(`time`) AS tm
FROM mytable 
WHERE `time` >= '2015-09-12 00:00:00' AND `time` <= '2015-09-12 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY HOUR(`time`)
) AS a ON m.time=a.tm 
GROUP BY HOUR(m.time)
ORDER BY m.time;
```